# Command line dotnet is trying to use a corporate nuget feed for an open source solution - how to get it to bypass that?

Tags: .net

I'm just trying to compile then run tests from the command line. I'm not trying to publish packages. Here's what I ran after I cloned https://github.com/wouter1981/commercial-model:

```
C:\Users\paul_h\scm\oss\commercial-model>dotnet build

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.0.0+c9eb9dd64 for .NET

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.102\NuGet.targets(130,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ourcompany/_packaging/ourcompany@Local/nuget/v3/index.json. [C:\Users\paul_h\scm\oss\commercial-model\CommercialModel.sln]

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.102\NuGet.targets(130,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\Users\paul_h\scm\oss\commercial-model\CommercialModel.sln]

Build FAILED.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.102\NuGet.targets(130,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ourcompany/_packaging/ourcompany@Local/nuget/v3/index.json. [C:\Users\paul_h\scm\oss\commercial-model\CommercialModel.sln]

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.102\NuGet.targets(130,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\Users\paul_h\scm\oss\commercial-model\CommercialModel.sln]

    0 Warning(s)

    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.60
```

Ideally, I am looking for an option to specify with the `dotnet` command in `cmd.exe` that will get it to skip the firm's feed and just pull dependencies from the public nuget feed. Say `--ignoreGlobalFeed`. I don't think it exists, so what is the alternative for .NET 6.x on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add specific NuGet config to solution folder

```
dotnet new nugetconfig
```

This will add new file `nuget.config`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!--To inherit the global NuGet package sources remove the <clear/> line below -->
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

And there you will be able to define package sources.

After that run

```
dotnet build
```

### Update

Or just add specific nuget feed to build command:

```
dotnet build --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Comment: The `--source` way worked fine for `build` but is unknown to `test` (see https://imgur.com/a/MZxmL9h). I then changed to the Nuget.Config you also showed and that worked fine too :)

Comment: Or you can use this command for testing:

```ps
dotnet build --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json && dotnet test --no-build
```

Building with `--source` option and than running `dotnet test` with `--no-build` flag.

Comment: I can make bash scripts for those two. Doh!